# online Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is Node.js mature enough to make entire web applications in it? I mean entirely in Node.js. I read somewhere that for some reason there should be (for example) nginx behind Node.js. Is it true? Can't Node.js stand alone? Are there any online websites built on Node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my opinion this isnt true anymore.
you can do two things:

1. use script like "forever" to monitor your node instance.
2. use this:
   http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/process.html#event_uncaughtException_
   to catch all exceptions that are not catched earlier

Comment: All of the answers are great! Thank you all! I set this answer as correct, because @Tereska has the least amount of reputation. :) +1 for all though.

Answer (score 4):

In the express [link](http://expressjs.com/applications.html), it shows a lot of good applications written by Node.js.

In my opinion, it is mature enough that node.js can be a standalone web application server. There are lots of lib modules supported different things in Nodejs already.

Answer (score 3):

Its absolutely mature enough. There are dozens of companies now that are using it in production for major features, and some that are even building their entire stacks with it.

If you want a well-rounded web framework, check out Express.

There are hundreds of modules that cover almost every type of feature you need, and they're mostly all easily accessible via npm (node package manager).

Over the summer I built a high-traffic Facebook app for a client using Node. Handles everything just fine.

Answer (score 2):

node v0.6 introduced [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), allowing multiple processes to fork and listen to a single socket.  This allows node to take advantage of multiple cores/cpus.  This was one of the big reasons to use something like nginx, as before cluster, a single node process would hog up an entire ip/port.